# Values with IN Operator used in CASE statement should count once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope this helps explain more than the title. Basically I have a query:

```
SELECT 
  e.USER
, e.CODE
, CASE WHEN 
  e.CODE IN ('a.01', 'b.04', 'c.20', x.01)
  THEN 1
  ELSE NULL
  END AS case
FROM TABLE e
```

That would get me:

```
USER   CODE     case
01     a.01     1
01     a.02     NULL
01     a.04     NULL
01     b.04     1
01     c.20     1
02     a.11     NULL
02     b.04     1
03     b.05     NULL
04     c.20     1
```

However, what I need is a bit more complicated. I need to group the codes up to give a single value per group per user `USER`:

For example:

```
, CASE WHEN 
  e.CODE IN ('a.01', 'b.04') --Group A
  OR
  e.CODE IN ('c.20', x.01)   --Group B
  THEN 1
  ELSE NULL
  END AS case
```

The above code is wrong, because what I need is if at least one of the codes in GROUP A or GROUP B is present for a user then only give one value of `1` ELSE `NULL`.

Something that would generate:

```
USER   CODE     case
01     a.01     1    --Group A
01     a.02     NULL
01     a.04     NULL
01     b.04     NULL --GROUP A, now NULL because we just need to count once per group 
01     c.20     1    --GROUP B
02     a.11     NULL
02     b.04     1   
03     b.05     NULL
04     c.20     1
```

If this helps, I eventually want to count the cases for each user to produce the following:

```
USER     count
01       2       --Not 3
02       1
03       1
04       1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the feedback. I'm posting an answer as it's working, but I'm not sure its the best answer:

```
SELECT
   t.USER
  ,t.CODE
  ,COUNT DISTINCT(t.case)

FROM (

SELECT 
  e.USER
, e.CODE
, CASE 
  WHEN e.CODE IN ('a.01', 'b.04') --Group A
  THEN 'grpA'
  WHEN e.CODE IN ('c.20', x.01)   --Group B
  THEN 'grpB'
  ELSE NULL
  END AS case

FROM TABLE e
) t

GROUP BY t.USER
```

I realize that will get me the results grouped by user, but that works to as I at the end, I just want to count cases by user. Not sure if someone can work with this for a better format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to set the value only once per user:

```
SELECT e.USER, e.CODE,
       (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY flag, e.USER ORDER BY e.code) = 1
             THEN flag
        END) as flag
FROM (SELECT e.*,
             (CASE WHEN e.CODE IN ('a.01', 'b.04', 'c.20', x.01) THEN 1 END) as flag
      FROM TABLE e
     ) e;
```

EDIT:

For the revised question in the comment:

```
SELECT e.USER, e.CODE,
       (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY flag, e.USER ORDER BY e.code) = 1
             THEN SIGN(flag)
        END) as flag
FROM (SELECT e.*,
             (CASE WHEN e.CODE IN ('a.01', 'b.04') THEN 1
                   WHEN e.CODE IN ('c.20', x.01) THEN 2
              END) as flag
      FROM TABLE e
     ) e;
```

Comment: Thanks. My bad, I should have clarified in the question (which I'll do now). I'll need them in 2 groups because one user may have a case where it appears in GROUP A and GROUP B. In which case, they should have `1` for each.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a smarter way, but this might do the trick if I'm understanding correctly:

```
SELECT sub.user,
       sub.code,
       CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                 ( PARTITION BY GroupCode
                       ORDER BY inGroup DESC
                 ) = 1 
             AND MAX(inGroup) OVER
                 ( PARTITION BY GroupCode
                 ) = 1 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END FieldYourAskingFor       
  FROM (SELECT e.*,
               CASE WHEN e.CODE IN ('a.01', 'b.04', 'c.20', x.01) THEN 1 
                END AS inGroup,
               CASE WHEN e.CODE IN ('a.01', 'b.04') THEN 'GroupA'
                    WHEN e.CODE IN ('c.20', x.01) THEN 'GroupB'
                END AS GroupCode
          FROM TABLE e
       ) sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `row_number()` with `case` expression :

```
select USER, CODE, 
       (case when row_number() over (partition by USER, grp order by CODE) = 1 and
                  grp is not null 
             then 1
        end) as case
from ( select *, (case when CODE IN ('a.01', 'b.04') then 'GA' 
                       when CODE IN ('c.20', 'x.01') then 'GB' 
                  end) as grp
       from table
    ) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I  would do it.

```
-- create test table and data
declare @tbl table(usr char(2), code char(4))
insert into @tbl values ('01', 'a.01'), ('01', 'b.04')
insert into @tbl values ('01', 'c.20'), ('02', 'b.04'), ('04', 'c.20')

-- actual query
select
   usr,
   sign(sum(iif(code in ('a.01', 'b.04'), 1, 0))) +          -- 1 if group a, else 0  
   sign(sum(iif(code in ('c.20', 'x.01'), 1, 0))) as count   -- 1 if group b, else 0
from @tbl
group by usr
```

The output is:

```
usr count
--- -----
01      2
02      1
04      1
```